# Part of my CSS isn't being applied

Tags: css

Originally my CSS was working fine for this particular section but for some reason which I can't figure out my CSS isn't being processed into the browser yet all my other CSS from that style sheet is fine. I know there has to be an error but I'm not sure what, with a fresh set of eyes I hope can help me out.

This is what I see:
[image]

```
<div id="service-contact-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div id="service-contact">
                <div class="service-contact-details">
                    <h3>Work With Me</h3>
                    <p>Please give me a call or use the contact form below</p>
                    <p class="service-contact-details-phone"> <a href="tel:000000 000000"> 000000 000000</a></p>
                </div>
                <?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='108' title='Contact form footer']"); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
/* Service Bottom Page Contact Form */
#service-contact-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #005E86;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#services-header {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.service-contact-details {
    text-align: center;
}

.service-contact-details h3 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
margin-top: 54px;
}

.service-contact-details p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.service-contact-details-phone {
    font-size: 22px !important;
}

#service-contact {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-control {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.service-contact-form-botton {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expect to work. Which parts of your markup are styles not being applied?

Comment: @PhillipChan Sorry for not making that clear the whole /* Service Bottom Page Contact Form */ CSS isn't being applied for some reason.

Comment: Can you pick one specific part of the style that's not being applied, and say how you can see that it's not being applied?

Comment: I put the code on JSfiddle and was able to get it to work which tells me it's something outside the code you provided which is throwing it off. https://jsfiddle.net/s80qung9/ It's a good idea to try to do that before posting so you can exclude environmental factors, which is what I suspect is going on.

Comment: Environmental factors could include 1) broken link to your CSS file 2) syntax error higher in the CSS code which is breaking the rest.

Comment: `service-contact-form-botton` seems like an unlikely class name. Could you have meant `-bottom`?

Comment: @PhillipChan that seems like the most plausible answer, thanks.